# How to add sub header to a header

Tags: tables, header-footer

I currently have a table with 8 columns and 5 rows that I would like to add a sub column that goes from C4 to C6. For instance, this the code below of my table

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth,center=\textwidth}
        \small
        \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrr}
          \hline
         c1 & c2 & c3 & c4  & c5 & c6 & c7 & c8 \\ 
          \hline
        r1 & 8.95e-04 & 7.35e-04 & 4.78e-06 &  10 & 0.52 & 0.67 & 0.30 \\ 
           r2 & 7.08e-21 & 2.09e-02 & 1.70e-26 &  54 & 0.55 & 0.64 & 0.25 \\ 
          r3 & 4.94e-04 & 5.50e-02 & 3.52e-06 &  17 & 0.38 & 0.61 & 0.13 \\ 
          r4 & 1.16e-06 & 6.65e-02 & 5.54e-08 &  10 & 0.52 & 0.62 & 0.28 \\ 
           r5 & 1.27e-05 & 8.61e-02 & 5.20e-07 &  10 & 0.53 & 0.66 & 0.27 \\ 
           \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \end{adjustbox}
        \caption{table example} 
        \end{table}
```

The output is this:[image: table1]

Hwoever, what I need to do is add a header on top of C4, C5, C6 and push C4, C5, C6 downwards. An illustraion of what I am trying to achieve:

[image: table2]

Where top-column is aligned with the other columns and the respective columns are under the top-column

Comment: For the combined column header, you can use the multicolumn command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, using `\multicolumn`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth,center=\textwidth}
        \small
        \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrr}
        \toprule
            c1 &       c2 &       c3 &                     c4 & c5 &   c6 &   c7 &   c8 \\
        \cmidrule(lr){4-6}
               &          &          & \multicolumn3r{c4--c6}             &      &      \\
        \midrule
            r1 & 8.95e-04 & 7.35e-04 &               4.78e-06 & 10 & 0.52 & 0.67 & 0.30 \\
            r2 & 7.08e-21 & 2.09e-02 &               1.70e-26 & 54 & 0.55 & 0.64 & 0.25 \\
            r3 & 4.94e-04 & 5.50e-02 &               3.52e-06 & 17 & 0.38 & 0.61 & 0.13 \\
            r4 & 1.16e-06 & 6.65e-02 &               5.54e-08 & 10 & 0.52 & 0.62 & 0.28 \\
            r5 & 1.27e-05 & 8.61e-02 &               5.20e-07 & 10 & 0.53 & 0.66 & 0.27 \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \end{adjustbox}
        \caption{table example} 
        \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\multicolumn{number of columns}{alignment}{text}` is probably self-explanatory. You can leave out the braces if your arguments are only a single token, which is what I tend to do --- hence I wrote `\multicolumn3r` instead of `\multicolumn{3}{r}` here. Functionally, they're identical.

I've also used the rules provided by the `booktabs` package to improve the overall look of the table.

BTW, for minus signs you may want to use `$-$` instead of `-`; the latter you'll get a dash, which is not the same.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, the `\multicolumn` command can be used for a shared column header. The following MWE also contains some off-topic suggestions with which you can improve your table: For the horizontal lines, I used commands from the `booktabs` package. In order to improve the alignment of numbers in the table columns, I used the `S` type column from the `siunitx` package. Since the use of `adjustbox` on a table inevitably leads to inconsistent font sizes throughout the document, something you might want to avoid, I removed the `adjustbox` environment entirely. The table should already be narrow enought to fit into the available textwidth. If you nevertheless insist on making the table exactly as wide as the textwidth, you might want to use `tabular*`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{table example}
    \begin{tabular}{r*{3}{S[table-format=1.2e-2]}S[table-format=2]*{3}{S[table-format=1.2]}}
      \toprule
      c1 & {c2}     & {c3}     &\multicolumn{3}{c}{common header} & {c7} & {c8} \\ \cmidrule{4-6}
         &          &          & {c4}     & {c5}& {c6} &      &    \\ 
      \midrule
      r1 & 8.95e-04 & 7.35e-04 & 4.78e-06 &  10 & 0.52 & 0.67 & 0.30 \\ 
      r2 & 7.08e-21 & 2.09e-02 & 1.70e-26 &  54 & 0.55 & 0.64 & 0.25 \\ 
      r3 & 4.94e-04 & 5.50e-02 & 3.52e-06 &  17 & 0.38 & 0.61 & 0.13 \\ 
      r4 & 1.16e-06 & 6.65e-02 & 5.54e-08 &  10 & 0.52 & 0.62 & 0.28 \\ 
      r5 & 1.27e-05 & 8.61e-02 & 5.20e-07 &  10 & 0.53 & 0.66 & 0.27 \\ 
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular} 
\end{table} 


\begin{table}[ht]
    \sisetup{output-exponent-marker=\ensuremath{\mathrm{E}}}
    \centering
    \caption{table example}
    \begin{tabular}{r*{3}{S[table-format=1.2e-2]}S[table-format=2]*{3}{S[table-format=1.2]}}
      \toprule
      c1 & {c2}     & {c3}     &\multicolumn{3}{c}{common header} & {c7} & {c8} \\ \cmidrule{4-6}
         &          &          & {c4}     & {c5}& {c6} &      &    \\ 
      \midrule
      r1 & 8.95e-04 & 7.35e-04 & 4.78e-06 &  10 & 0.52 & 0.67 & 0.30 \\ 
      r2 & 7.08e-21 & 2.09e-02 & 1.70e-26 &  54 & 0.55 & 0.64 & 0.25 \\ 
      r3 & 4.94e-04 & 5.50e-02 & 3.52e-06 &  17 & 0.38 & 0.61 & 0.13 \\ 
      r4 & 1.16e-06 & 6.65e-02 & 5.54e-08 &  10 & 0.52 & 0.62 & 0.28 \\ 
      r5 & 1.27e-05 & 8.61e-02 & 5.20e-07 &  10 & 0.53 & 0.66 & 0.27 \\ 
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular} 
\end{table} 

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{table example}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{r@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{3}{S[table-format=1.2e-2]}S[table-format=2]*{3}{S[table-format=1.2]}}
      \toprule
      c1 & {c2}     & {c3}     &\multicolumn{3}{c}{common header} & {c7} & {c8} \\ \cmidrule{4-6}
         &          &          & {c4}     & {c5}& {c6} &      &    \\ 
      \midrule
      r1 & 8.95e-04 & 7.35e-04 & 4.78e-06 &  10 & 0.52 & 0.67 & 0.30 \\ 
      r2 & 7.08e-21 & 2.09e-02 & 1.70e-26 &  54 & 0.55 & 0.64 & 0.25 \\ 
      r3 & 4.94e-04 & 5.50e-02 & 3.52e-06 &  17 & 0.38 & 0.61 & 0.13 \\ 
      r4 & 1.16e-06 & 6.65e-02 & 5.54e-08 &  10 & 0.52 & 0.62 & 0.28 \\ 
      r5 & 1.27e-05 & 8.61e-02 & 5.20e-07 &  10 & 0.53 & 0.66 & 0.27 \\ 
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*} 
\end{table} 
        
\end{document}
```